# Would you ever use mutableStateOf{} without remember{} and/or vice-versa?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm having a hard time understanding why `mutableStateOf` and `remember` are 2 separate functions.

I understand `remember` exists to save calculations across recompositions and `mutableStateOf` is observed by compose and every change leads to a recomposition. With this in mind it's natural to see the construct `remember { mutableStateOf {} }`. Every state change causes a recomposition and `remember` will remember the old state.

If I just use `mutableStateOf { }`, changes to the state will lead to a recomposition but since the state isn't remembered it'll just be recreated anyway. On the other hand, if I use just `remember { }` it'll remember a value that never changes, so why would I even bother remembering it?

What am I missing? How could these be useful separately?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of them has their uses. remember alone stores object that doesn't need to be updated on each recomposition while there are states to trigger recomposition, mutableState wrapping is widely used with default `remember` functions.

### remember(key1, key2,...){SomeObject}

This is useful when you don't need to calculation or create instance of objects like bitmap on each recomposition but when any of the keys change.

For instance, you can create a `Bitmap` or `AnnotatedString`, `Paint` or some object that doesn't need to trigger recomposition because another state already changes recomposition such as uses gesture events or adding inputs via `TextField`.

The one below is an image creation function i use in my image Composable library which only create ImageBitmap based on param changes.

```
@Composable
internal fun getScaledImageBitmap(
    imageWidth: Dp,
    imageHeight: Dp,
    rect: IntRect,
    bitmap: ImageBitmap,
    contentScale: ContentScale
): ImageBitmap {

    val scaledBitmap =
        remember(bitmap, rect, imageWidth, imageHeight, contentScale) {
            // This bitmap is needed when we crop original bitmap due to scaling mode
            // and aspect ratio result of cropping
            // We might have center section of the image after cropping, and
            // because of that thumbLayout either should have rectangle and some
            // complex calculation for srcOffset and srcSide along side with touch offset
            // or we can create a new bitmap that only contains area bounded by rectangle
            Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmap.asAndroidBitmap(),
                rect.left,
                rect.top,
                rect.width,
                rect.height
            ).asImageBitmap()
        }
    return scaledBitmap
}
```

or remember result of text measurement only when style or text changes

```
    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    // text and style can be params of a function and you
    // you don't have to calculate every time recomposition
    // happens unless these params change
    val textToDraw = "A"
   
    val style = TextStyle(
        fontSize = 150.sp,
        color = Color.Black,
        background = Color.Red.copy(alpha = 0.2f)
    )

    val textLayoutResult = remember(textToDraw, style) {
        textMeasurer.measure(textToDraw, style)
    }
```

### mutableStateOf without remember

You can put `MutableState`s inside a ViewModel or a presenter that doesn't need with remember or you can bundle multiple `MutableState`s inside a class and bundle them with a single rememberX function which is widely used with default remember functions such as `rememberScrollState` and so on.

A popular one is [JetSnack sample](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetsnack/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetsnack/ui/home/search/Search.kt) of google

```
@Stable
class SearchState(
    query: TextFieldValue,
    focused: Boolean,
    searching: Boolean,
    categories: List<SearchCategoryCollection>,
    suggestions: List<SearchSuggestionGroup>,
    filters: List<Filter>,
    searchResults: List<Snack>
) {
    var query by mutableStateOf(query)
    var focused by mutableStateOf(focused)
    var searching by mutableStateOf(searching)
    var categories by mutableStateOf(categories)
    var suggestions by mutableStateOf(suggestions)
    var filters by mutableStateOf(filters)
    var searchResults by mutableStateOf(searchResults)
    val searchDisplay: SearchDisplay
        get() = when {
            !focused && query.text.isEmpty() -> SearchDisplay.Categories
            focused && query.text.isEmpty() -> SearchDisplay.Suggestions
            searchResults.isEmpty() -> SearchDisplay.NoResults
            else -> SearchDisplay.Results
        }
}
```

And wrapped with remember

```
@Composable
private fun rememberSearchState(
    query: TextFieldValue = TextFieldValue(""),
    focused: Boolean = false,
    searching: Boolean = false,
    categories: List<SearchCategoryCollection> = SearchRepo.getCategories(),
    suggestions: List<SearchSuggestionGroup> = SearchRepo.getSuggestions(),
    filters: List<Filter> = SnackRepo.getFilters(),
    searchResults: List<Snack> = emptyList()
): SearchState {
    return remember {
        SearchState(
            query = query,
            focused = focused,
            searching = searching,
            categories = categories,
            suggestions = suggestions,
            filters = filters,
            searchResults = searchResults
        )
    }
}
```

or remmberScrollState

```
@Stable
class ScrollState(initial: Int) : ScrollableState {

    /**
     * current scroll position value in pixels
     */
    var value: Int by mutableStateOf(initial, structuralEqualityPolicy())
        private set

    /**
     * maximum bound for [value], or [Int.MAX_VALUE] if still unknown
     */
    var maxValue: Int
        get() = _maxValueState.value
        internal set(newMax) {
            _maxValueState.value = newMax
            if (value > newMax) {
                value = newMax
            }
        }

    /**
     * Size of the viewport on the scrollable axis, or 0 if still unknown.
     */
    internal var viewportSize: Int by mutableStateOf(0, structuralEqualityPolicy())

    /**
     * [InteractionSource] that will be used to dispatch drag events when this
     * list is being dragged. If you want to know whether the fling (or smooth scroll) is in
     * progress, use [isScrollInProgress].
     */
    val interactionSource: InteractionSource get() = internalInteractionSource

    internal val internalInteractionSource: MutableInteractionSource = MutableInteractionSource()

    private var _maxValueState = mutableStateOf(Int.MAX_VALUE, structuralEqualityPolicy())

 // Rest of the class
}
```

And remember function

```
@Composable
fun rememberScrollState(initial: Int = 0): ScrollState {
    return rememberSaveable(saver = ScrollState.Saver) {
        ScrollState(initial = initial)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the examples are great. Makes total sense to me now that's one would remember a bitmap instead of creating it in every recomposition. I think the mutableStateOf examples one can still argue that they will eventually end up inside remembers but I see everyone's giving this example. Thanks a lot

Comment: You can also put this wrapped up class inside a ViewModel which we do in our project. We use some uiState inside ViewModel that contains many `MutableState`s and get or boolean functions like `SearchState`. Purpose of remember is to give memory to functions. Since we can  contain that class inside a ViewModel we don't need use remember at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a larger model that you remember and it has many mutable states inside, something like this:

```
class PagerState {
    var currentPage by mutableStateOf(0)
    var pageCount by mutableStateOf(0)
    var currentPageOffset by mutableStateOf(0F)
}

@Composable fun Pager() {
    val state = remember { PagerState() }
}
```

This is simplified code from actual [Pager](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/ffcdff8747530b92aa5a9eacd926708de9488da7:frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/compose/core/src/com/android/compose/pager/PagerState.kt;l=87) from compose library. There are many such states in the compose library - `PagerState`, `ScrollState`, `LazyListState`, ... They usually come with their own remember function like `rememberLazyListState()`, but that's not necessary. Inside of that function is simply something like `remember { PagerState() }`. You can of course create your own states like this when it makes sense for you.

Comment: I think we can argue that this is still using `remember { mutableStateOf }` but at a different scale

Comment: Well yes, but it explains why it's not just single function doing both things I guess.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've edited my comment but somehow it isn't there. I do acknowledge that. I get it that it's a way of using it separately. Thank you very much for the help.